# Can jetty integrate with Apache similar to hot Tomcat does with mod_jk?

Tags: tomcat, apache2, jetty, mod-jk

AS the question says

"Can jetty integrate with Apache similar to hot Tomcat does with mod_jk?"

We are really looking to leave Tomcat.

Comment: what issues are you having with tomcat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually use mod_jk with Jetty as well, but mod_proxy seems to be the preferred way: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Apache